# Run scheduled task once a day on Android

Tags: android, android-alarms, mobile-development, android-jobscheduler

My Android application helps users to follow their daily plan by sending notifications at a specific time. This task is easy to solve with JobScheduler. It seems easy, light and up to date solution.

What I'm struggling with is how to plan all notifications every day. I need to run code that checks user daily plan and schedules notification every day at midnight silently. And so far I found 2 approaches

**Use JobService.** It can be re-scheduled with

> public final void jobFinished(JobParameters params, boolean needsReschedule)

but I think it's a bad solution because

1. I'll need to treat finished job as failed, although it's successful
2. Schedule time will increase linearly/exponentially and that is not acceptable for me.

**Another approach is to use AlarmManager**, but it also has a couple of drawbacks

1. According to documentation

> Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.

And this is not acceptable, as my users can miss something important.

2. I've read that it kills battery pretty quickly. Is that true?

**Other solutions** that I've found in documentation doesn't looks like what I need.
(https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Any ideas how run scheduled task on a daily basis that will be light and resilient to reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Using JobService is fine. You do not need to reschedule your job. Just create new job(s) as needed.

Comment: Good idea. But based on comment below I also need to take into account Doze mode because it can postpone JobScheduler execution. So as far as I understand I can implement this feature with JobScheduler as well as with AlarmManger and the only trade off is between battery consumption and schedule time precision. Well, at least it's good to have a few choices. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have my own issues with scheduling alarms too. To have things worse, starting with Android 6 there's Doze mode which delays alarms execution.

Please take a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

For alarms, you can have a boot complete listener and reschedule the alarms on a restart. If you don't need network connectivity during alarm firing, take a look at **Adapting your app to Doze** from the above link.

Comment: Looks like AlarmManger can satisfy my requirements with setAndAllowWhileIdle() method. The only concern I have now is battery consumption. From documentation
"These alarms can significantly impact the power use of the device when idle (and thus cause significant battery blame to the app scheduling them), so they should be used with care"
So most likely I'll need to do some experiments/researches to figure out how expensive is AlarmManger in terms of batter life. I'm new to Android, so missed Doze mode sections. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: From my experience so far, `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle' seems to fire at needed time the only downside is that it seems that you do not have network connectivity during the alarm firing. So using it for local things should work. From what I understood, during Doze mode, alarms and jobs are being postponed to the next maintenance windows, so having job scheduler doesn't seem to help in your case. To have things worse JobScheduler is available from android 21+ and for older version there is Firebase JobDispacther but at the moment it seems to use only the GooglePlayDriver even in androdid 5...